# How do I find OS architecture in Google Dart?

Tags: dart

How can I find the `OS's architecture` using Dart on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Platform`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/Platform.html) class:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  print(Platform.operatingSystem);
  print(Platform.numberOfProcessors);
}
```

If the `Platform` class is not enough, you could also create a new process and execute some command to see if it returns something meaningful (like execute `ps` to retrieve processes, etc.).